# Why the difference between a loan and a prozbul with respect to antedating and postdating?

Tags: maseches-sheviis, pruzbul

Mishnah Shevi'it 10:5 says:

A pre-dated prozbul is valid, but a post-dated one, is invalid. Pre-dated loan documents [of loans] are invalid, but post-dated one valid. 
Source: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sheviit.10.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Why are a prozbul and a loan document treated in this opposite fashion concerning pre and post dating?

Answer (score 2):

[Rav Ovadia Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Sheviit.10.5.1?lang=bi) there explains the differentiation as follows. The Prozbul dictates that all loans made *prior* to the writing of the actual Prozbul are to be given to the Beis Din during the Shemitah year, thus allowing the lender to collect them afterward. Therefore, if one pre-dates his Prozbul then it prevents him from being able to collect any other loans that he lent *after* the writing of the Prozbul, as the Shemita year cancels them.

For example:
Reuven lent 100 dollars to Shimon 2 months before the coming of the Shemitah year (The month of Tamuz of the 6th year). In order to allow Reuven to collect the loan from Shimon after the Shemita year, we write a Prozbul that states that the loan will be given into the jurisdiction of the Beis Din during the Shemitah year. Now, this Prozbul only dictates that the loan of 100 dollars will be given into the jurisdiction of Beis Din, however any other loans Reuven lends to Shimon afterward, let's say in the last month before the Shemitah year, will not be included in the Prozbul and will become void at the start of the Shemitah Year. It is therefore in the best interest of the lender, in our case Reuven, to delay writing the Prozbul as late as possible. If Reuven decides to pre-date the Prozbul, it is only to his detriment, as he is preventing himself the opportunity to collect any loans he may make after the writing of the Prozbul. It is for this reason, a predated Prozbul is valid (We are always concerned for the borrower and not for the lender).

If the Prozbul was post-dated it is invalid as it is a detriment to the borrower, for it doesn't allow the loans that were made after the writing of the Prozbul to become void, and thus the lender will collect from the borrower unlawfully. Using our example above, the writing of the Prozbul took place 2 months before the Shemita year. Now, let's say that Reuven lent an additional 50 dollars to Shimon 1 month before the Shemita year, after the writing of the Prozbul. This 50 dollar loan should become void at the start of the Shemita year as it was not included in the Prozbul. However, if Reuven post-dated the Prozbul with the date of the Prozbul being from 1 month before the Shemita year, this allows Reuven to collect the additional loan of 50 dollars, when it actuality this loan was lent afterward, thus unlawfully collecting the 50 dollars, for it was bound to be void at the start of the Shemita year.

Standard monetary loan documents work in the opposite direction. When this loan document is post-dated, it is to the detriment of the lender and is therefore valid. When the loan document is pre-dated then it is to the detriment of the borrower and therefore rendered invalid.

For example:
Reuven lent 100 dollars to Shimon on the 15th of Nissan. The loan document should dictate this exact date, so that if the borrower sells property afterward to a third party, let's call him Levi, then Reuven has the right to collect that property from Levi as he was owed that money prior to Levi's purchase. This is essentially what a lien on a property is.

If the loan document was pre-dated and stated that the loan took place on the 1st of Nissan, this would allow Reuven to collect any property that the borrower sold prior to the 15th, the actual date of the loan, in an unlawful manner, as those sales were outside the realm of the loan. This is why a pre-dated loan document is invalid. (Anecdotal Note: not only is the loan document invalid in that it doesn't allow Reuven to collect property sold by Shimon from *before* the 15th, it doesn't even allow Reuven to collect from property sold by Shimon *after* the 15th, this is a consequence that the Beis Din enacts in order to reprimand Reuven for trying to essentially steal from Shimon.)

If the loan document was post-dated and stated that the loan took place on the 1st of Iyar, this would restrict Reuven from being able to collect any properties sold by Shimon after the 15th, a detriment to himself as the lender. It is for this reason that a postdated loan document is valid.

Comment: The halacha is that shemitah cancels debts at its end, not its beginning

Comment: Why would a post-dated document not just become effective on its date? Why would a post-dated Prozbul have any effect on a borrower, since the date is clear for all to see?

Comment: @YehudaW I'm not quite sure what you are asking exactly

Comment: @MosheMoskowitz I assumed that the person borrowing money would ask to see the lender's prosbul.  Perhaps that is not a reasonable assumption.

Comment: That's a good question. The best way to prevent this problem seemingly would be to proofread the shtar (document) beforehand. Yet even this is not foolproof for the lender could draw up another shtar with a false date on it. If your follow up question will be (ve'im tomar) "why doesn't the borrower keep a copy of the shtar?" I don't know the answer, its a major question.

Comment: It seems the general practice was to have both parties agree on a date and leave one party responsible for drawing up the shtar. It isn't always the lender who is responsible for the writing of the shtar, the borrower can draw up the shtar as well, see Bava Basra 167b. The way we avoid these issues is by having eidei re'iyah (witnesses who testify to the event taking place) as well as eidei chasimah (witnesses who sign that the shtar is valid). Nonetheless,  verbal loans (milveh al peh) and a written loan (milveh b'shtar) are rendered effective even without these witnesses

Comment: Your answer presumes a prosbul can have effect only on loans made after the prosbul was issued.  Is that true?

Comment: Also, how can a prozbul have an affect on loans that are not yet in existence?

Comment: @YehudaW It is the exact opposite. A prosbul only maintains the validity of loans made before the writing of the prosbul.

Comment: What stops a lender from writing another prozbul at a later date? That would be similar to a post dated prozbul.